# R: dplyr::arrange (ver. 1.1.0) returns unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr::arrange ver. 1.1.0 returned unexpected results when I ran an old program. Is this by design or an error that is likely to be patched? See example below.

Regards,
Martin

```r
# example data 
a <- c("aa", "BB", "Anslag", "bb") 
b <- c(1,2,3,4) 
c <- data.frame(a, b) 
c 
# arrange 
dplyr::arrange(c, a)
```

expected (verified w. vers. 1.0.10): aa, Anslag, BB, bb

actual (w 1.1.0): Anslag, BB, aa, bb

Comment: This is by design. See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-pick-reframe-arrange/#arrange As mentioned in the post you could get the "old" behavior by setting `options(dplyr.legacy_locale = TRUE)`.

Comment: But of course we would much rather you use the new `.locale = "en"` argument instead if it really does matter.

Comment: Could someone post the info from these comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the tidyverse blog](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-pick-reframe-arrange/#arrange) this is by design:

> When sorting character vectors, the C locale is now the default, rather than the system locale

But as mentioned in the post you could get the "old" behavior by setting `options(dplyr.legacy_locale = TRUE)` or as @DavisVaughan mentioned in the comments by explicitly setting the locale via the new `.locale` argument:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  a = c("aa", "BB", "Anslag", "bb"), 
  b = c(1,2,3,4)
)
withr::with_options(list(dplyr.legacy_locale = TRUE), dplyr::arrange(dat, a))
#>        a b
#> 1     aa 1
#> 2 Anslag 3
#> 3     bb 4
#> 4     BB 2

dplyr::arrange(dat, a, .locale = "en")
#>        a b
#> 1     aa 1
#> 2 Anslag 3
#> 3     bb 4
#> 4     BB 2
```

Comment: Or simply base R: `c[order(c$a), ]`

Comment: @s_baldur ( and  stefan, DavisVaughan and BenBolker)  thank you all for answering, will adapt code to new behaviour! Regards, Martin